# ERROR "pinging failed for distributed lock pinger :: caused by :: LockStateChangeFailed: findAndModify query predicate didn't match any lock document"

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Have setup the config server and the replicate set. But I am unable to start mongos. The following error appears

ERROR "pinging failed for distributed lock pinger :: caused by :: LockStateChangeFailed: findAndModify query predicate didn't match any lock document"